# How to deal with accented characters in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch IP details of the user from the following url:
http://freegeoip.net/json/186.80.156.123

Now if you open up the above URL, you will see that the `city` parameter has an weird character in place of an accented character...how can I fix it before displaying in php?

my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://freegeoip.net/json/".trim($user->ip_address));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$jout = json_decode($curl_out);
echo $jout->city.", ".$jout->region_name.", ".$jout->country_name;
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly. You have encoding issues, you probably don't have utf-8 encoding.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it? cause this finally solved it though I don't know why utf8_decode didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It is encoded in UTF-8 but you are interpreting it as ISO-8859-1.

Either set the appropriate options, or just run the `$curl_out` value through `utf8_decode()`.

Comment: I tried $curl_out = utf8_decode($curl_out); and json decode failed, I also tried doing it on $jout->city, but I still get same character issue.

Comment: Ah, right, because the JSON expects valid UTF-8... Hmm... it should just work, really...